# Computing article abstracts

Tags: python, markdown

I'm looking for a way to automatically produce an abstract, basically the first few sentances/paragraphs of a blog entry, to display in a list of articles (which are written in markdown).  Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
def abstract(article, paras=3):
    return '\n'.join(article.split('\n')[0:paras])
```

to just grab the first few lines worth of text, but i'm not totally happy with the results.

What I'm really looking for is to end up with about 1/3 of a screenful of formatted text to display in the list of entries, but using the algorithm above, the amount pulled ends up with wildly varying amounts, as little as a line or two, is frequently mixed with more ideal sized abstracts.

Is there a library that's good at this kind of thing? if not, do you have any suggestions to improve the output?

Comment: What does "not totally happy" mean?  Can you give examples of "wrong" and "right" abstracts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can do something like this:

```
from textwrap import wrap

def getAbstract(text, lines=5, screenwidth=100):
    width = len(' '.join([
               line for block in text.splitlines()
               for line in wrap(block, width=screenwidth)
            ][:lines]))
    return text[:width] + '...'
```

This makes use of the textwrap algorithm to get the ideal text length. It will break the text into screen-sized lines and use them to calculate the length of the desirable number of lines.

For example applying this algorithm on the [python wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) entry:

```
print getAbstract(text, lines=7)
```

will give you this output:

> Python is a general-purpose high-level
>   programming language.[2](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) Its design
>   philosophy emphasizes code
>   readability.[3] Python claims to
>   "[combine] remarkable power with very
>   clear syntax",[4] and its standard
>   library is large and comprehensive.
>   Its use of indentation as block
>   delimiters is unusual among popular
>   programming languages.
>
> Python supports multiple programming
>   paradigms (primarily object oriented,
>   imperative, and functional) and
>   features a fully dynamic type system
>   and automatic memory management,
>   similar to Perl, Ruby, Scheme, and
>   Tcl. Like other dynamic languages,
>   Python is often used as a scripting...

---

Without further details it's hard to help you. But if your problem was that taking the first few lines was too much for some entries you may need to have a look at [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html)

For example if you only want 100 character abstracts you can do the following:

```
import textwrap

abstract = textwrap.wrap(text, 100)[0]
```

That will also replace newlines with spaces which might be desirable depending on your requirements.

Comment: Doug Hellman also has a nice writeup on textwrap in his Python Module of the Week blog: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/textwrap/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what you want.

However, I would suggest cutting the article after X characters and put "...". Then you have more control over the size of your "abstract" (if that's what bothers you in your current implementation).